# Graph of Extracted Links

Tags: scrapy

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to get some analytics on the links extracted by a crawler? I know there is the analytics API but I can't quite figure out how to use it and the docs are pretty scant.

I'm trying to troubleshoot why my crawler is extracting some links but not others. For example, I start my crawl on a home page in which there are links to URLs containing the word `business` but the following rule will not return any items.

```
rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('business', )), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )
```

It would be great if there is a way to log some sort of graph of extracted links but I cannot find a way to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easier way to test your rule is to test your `LinkExtractor` obj using `scrapy shell` and assuming you're talking about the `CrawlSpider` I think there's no built-in way of doing that. Nonetheless, if you want to generate some sort of directed graph you could subclass the `LinkeExtractor` and overwrite the `extract_links` method to print the "graph edges" like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('VerboseLinkExtractor')
class VerboseLinkExtractor(LinkExtractor):
    def extract_links(self, response):
        links = super(Graph, self).extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            logger.debug("{} ==> {}".format(response.url, link.url)) # or a simple print
        return links
```

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding scrapy LinkExtractor's parameters:

> allow (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) **urls must match** in order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match all links.

You can test your linkextractors in python shell:

```
>: from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
>: from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
>: body = "<a href=/somewhere.html>business</a>"
>: resp = HtmlResponse('http://example.com', 200, body=body, encoding='utf8')
>: LinkExtractor().extract_links(resp)
<: [Link(url='http://example.com/somewhere.html', text='business', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
>: LinkExtractor(allow='business').extract_links(resp)
<: []
```

To match text you can use `restrict_xpath` parameter:

```
>: LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[contains(text(),"business")]').extract_links(re
   sp)
<: [Link(url='http://example.com/somewhere.html', text='business', fragment='', nofollow=False)]
```

Check out official docs for [LinkExtractor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)

Comment: The URLs I am attempting to match have the form `http://example.com/business/etc/etc.html`. Having read the docs already, I understand that LinkExtractors are analyzing the content of the URL, not the Link text. These links are actually on my start URL but are being missed - hence my question is about debugging the graph of extracted links. Thanks for the example of using the shell though,  that was useful.